# SharePoint Online Check Permissions

Tags: sharepoint-online

I'm trying to troubleshoot a permissions issue for a client on SharePoint Online.

I'm looking at the list of users who have permissions - you can see in the screenshot that someone called Jennifer has Read access.

However, when I go to use Check Permissions and type in that name, it says "We couldn't find an exact match".

[image: Check permissions]

What's going wrong that's preventing from using Check Permissions against a user who is clearly there?

More info:

- The user is internal, i.e. their email address is in the org that is using that tenant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just answered my own question!  I got access to the main admin console, and I see that this user (and many others that I was trying Check Permissions with) are Unlicensed!  If I use Check Permissions against a licensed user, it is just fine.